# why equalsIgnoreCase() don't use toLowerCase() only?

Tags: java

why equalsIgnoreCase() use  toUpperCase() firstly, and toLowerCase() to avoid the mistaken identification of Georgian alphabet, rather than use toLowerCase() for the first time and only use it?

```
public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset,
        String other, int ooffset, int len) {
    char ta[] = value;
    int to = toffset;
    char pa[] = other.value;
    int po = ooffset;
    // Note: toffset, ooffset, or len might be near -1>>>1.
    if ((ooffset < 0) || (toffset < 0)
            || (toffset > (long)value.length - len)
            || (ooffset > (long)other.value.length - len)) {
        return false;
    }
    while (len-- > 0) {
        char c1 = ta[to++];
        char c2 = pa[po++];
        if (c1 == c2) {
            continue;
        }
        if (ignoreCase) {
            // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
            // try converting both characters to uppercase.
            // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
            // continue.
            char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if (u1 == u2) {
                continue;
            }
            // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
            // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
            // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
            // exiting.
            if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no evidence to preclude that other character sets dont work properly with converting to lower case. They seem to be just playing it safe here.

Comment: thanks, I find the answer in the  duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it's using `toLowerCase` on the *result* of `toUpperCase` (`u1` and `u2`), not on the original characters (`c1` and `c2`). What it's checking is that `c1` converted to upper case (`u1`) and then converted to lower case matches `c2` converted to upper case (`u2`) and then converted to lower case. So it can't just skip the initial `toUpperCase`, it's using the information it got from that (`u1` and `u2`).